# sparql - regex doesn't work as case insensitive

Tags: sparql

I'm using SemWeb.Sparql.dll in C# to execute some queries in sparql via C# 
I need to compare a given string variable to string in my ontology (rdfs:label) but i need this compare case insensitive ,so I used the regex function. I used this query:

```
disease = "'^" + disease + "'";
string query = prefixes + @"
               Select ?a ?name Where{
               ?a ?c owl:Class .
               ?a rdfs:label ?name.
               FILTER (Regex(?name," + @disease + ",'i'))}";
```

which is work properly in some cases and doesn't in others.can anyone help me.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using SemWeb?  SemWeb ceased active development in 2010 and doesn't support any of the newer SPARQL 1.1 standard.  Have you considered dotNetRDF (http://www.dotnetrdf.org) as an alternative? (*disclaimer - I develop this*)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following:

```
FILTER (regex(str(?name), ...
```

i.e. wrap `?name` in `str()`. That will ensure the first argument is a string.

Comment: I used it, but the result is same. It doesn't much case insensitive in some cases

Comment: Ok, when you say 'some cases' do you mean "some diseases don't match", or "for a given disease some labels that ought to match don't"?

Comment: I mean :"for a given disease some labels that ought to match don't"